# rawPassword cannot be null exception

Tags: java, spring, security, passwords, bcrypt

I have the following problem:

I want to test if a user registers successfully. I'm not doing this over a UI but via Postman. The problem is that I get an exception when I use the POST Command. I have already checked all annotations.

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoPWi.png)

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **rawPassword cannot be null**
> at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:103) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
> at com.example.application.backend.data.service.UserService.singUpUser(UserService.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.example.application.backend.data.registration.RegistrationService.register(RegistrationService.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.example.application.backend.data.registration.RegistrationController.register(RegistrationController.java:18)

**This is my UserService Class:**

```
private final static  String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG = "user with email %s not found";
@Autowired
private final UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public UserService(
        UserRepository userRepository,
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
            .orElseThrow(() ->
                    new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
}

public String singUpUser(User user) {
    boolean userExists = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).isPresent();

    if(userExists){
        throw new IllegalStateException("email already taken");
    }

    String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());

    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

    userRepository.save(user);

    return "it works";
}
```

**Registration Service Class:**

```
@Autowired
private final UserService userService;
private final EmailValidator emailValidator;

public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
    boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());
    if (!isValidEmail) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("email not valid");
    }
    return userService.singUpUser(
            new User(
                    request.getFirstName(),
                    request.getLastName(),
                    request.getEmail(),
                    request.getPassword(),
                    UserRole.USER
            )
    );
}

public RegistrationService(UserService userService, EmailValidator emailValidator) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.emailValidator = emailValidator;
}
```

**Registration Controller Class:**

```
@Autowired
private RegistrationService registrationService;

@PostMapping
public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
    return registrationService.register(request);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when the password string that is fed to the bCryptEncoder is empty or null.

In your UserService.java class,

```
String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
```

user.getPassword() is null, which means in RegistrationService.java class,

```
request.getPassword()
```

is fetching a null value.

Please check if you are getting the correct parameter name for password from the request object. If possible, add some logger statements in your code and debug.

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8317)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I debug my code and deleted the empty constructor in the User Class. The getter is not null anymore, but I have another exception:                   
not-null property references a null or transient value : com.example.application.backend.data.entity.User.department

Answer (score 2):

Expanding @Sidharth's answer.
For anyone experiencing this problem check your password getter at AppUser.java class. It is probably returning null.

Change

```
public String getPassword(){return null;}
```

To

```
public String getPassword(){return password;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working. The problem was that the `@Column` annotations were set to `nullable` `false`.

Answer (score 0):

please pay attention when we import the module request body

make sure the import is `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;`